# Unity editor's internal compiler throws Unhandled Exception for no reason

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Unity editor throws the following for EVERY field in EVERY class:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Mono.CSharp.InternalErrorException: Assets/MyClass.cs: MyClass.AnyObjectOrFunction --->  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> at Mono.CSharp.TypeParameterInflator.Inflate (Mono.CSharp.TypeSpec type) [0x00098] in <1fff364146884fcdb77ba25fbd1b417a>:0

The project in visual studio does not show any errors. Also keep in mind that I have the same Unity version in another machine with the same project and everything is fine. I also updated Unity (to 2018.2.1) just in case. I use runtime scripting version NET 4.x

Comment: You're going to need more specific cases to help with this. "NullReferenceException" is one of the most common exceptions people encounter in C# and it's generally something like "You tried to use an object before the object was created" but without actual examples it's impossible to say.

Comment: This was happening at compilation time that was the weird thing. It turned out that I was using a dependency dll that was using local functions, and I am guessing that Unity current version does not support this. It didn't throw any reasonable error; only NullReferenceException for every field in classes (even a function)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using a dependency dll that was using local functions, and I am guessing that Unity current version does not support. It didn't throw any reasonable error though; only NullReferenceException for every field (even a function) of many classes